# Manually block sleep and screen locking - Suspend Problem

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery

On Kubuntu 22.04
In the Battery and Brightness settings in the taskbar I have the following options and wonder what is the purpose:

(unticked): “Manually block sleep and screen locking.”
“Activity Manager is currently blocking sleep and screen locking (This activity's policies prevent screen power management)”

And I have ticked the manual blocking but it returns back to unticked after each booting.

I never used that Activity Manager and wonder why is it doing that and what's the meaning and consequence of this?

Because sometimes I noticed when I close the laptop’s lid it seems not to be really in suspend  (which is ticked in Power Management settings - sometimes I hear the hard drive starts spinning)

And the battery consumption is pretty high in suspend, which is about 12%/h  which I never experienced in older laptops. This now is an  VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA.

Once the laptop battery was charged at 18%, I opened Firefox (having around 7-8 tabs open from last session) and suddenly really within two seconds the battery was at 0%, the device turned in suspend mode immediately. . . shock !

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of "Manually block sleep and screen locking" it has to be on *"Do not use special settings"* in the Energieverwaltung (German System), somthing like Power Management or Energy Saving, there in the second menu *Energy settings for activities* .

It is then really in suspend when the lid is closed.
Before it was on *Define a special behavior*
Regarding the energy consumption I am using now Gnome Disks and have set to suspend the second HDD after 10seconds. That helps a lot.